# How to align picture left and text right changing only css

Tags: html, css

I have a task to make a structure exactly as shown in the picture. But text and picture cannot seem to listen to me. I have tried to align, float, width and other properties but none of them seem to work. It is funny I can't do that since it is quite simple. May you help me?

[image: how it should look]

```css
/* Make changes anywhere you need in CSS. Create CSS pseudo-elements if you need them. */

.box {
 border: 5px solid #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
 max-width: 500px;
 
}

.box__image {
 border-radius: 20px;
   padding:21px;
   float: left;
}

.box__text{
}

.box__wrapper {
   
}


.box__title {
 font-weight: 700;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.box__link {
 text-decoration: underline;
   color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-transform: capitalize;
   
}
```

```html
<section class="task">
  <div class="task__holder">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="box__image" src="https://dbcms.s3.amazonaws.com/devbridgecom/bcms/image/cdb81346f5ec4f708a53c58c48dbb288/knight-king-small.png" alt="#">
      <div class="box__wrapper">
        <h2 class="box__title">The Night King</h2>
        <p class="box__text">The Night King was created by the Children of the Forest during the Wars of the First Men and the Children of the Forest and remained alive for about 10,000 years. It can be assumed the magic that transformed him also gave him his longevity.</p>
        <p class="box__text">
          The Night King was the master and the first of the <a href="#" class="box__link">white walkers</a>, having existed since the age of the First Men. He was also the supreme leader of the Army of the Dead.
        </p>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This looks like a school assignment for you buddy. What do you think that needs to be changed? You can read more about CSS at the following site:  https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: I try to float text to right wtih float:right and image to left using float: left but that does not work for me. Okay, I know that is easy for those who know but I am struggling with this for  2 hours already

Comment: I'd go creating two divs, each floating left. In the first I'd put the picture and in the other the text. Easy enough

Comment: Note that I am not allowed to change my html

Comment: I made a code pen: https://codepen.io/Vytautel/pen/KKPYzEz

Comment: note that you are not allowed to scream also

Comment: ok try to give margin from left to "box__wrapper" div to calculate image width and padding from left and right

Answer (score 3):

Just make us of `flex` layout.

I always prefer to go for flex box layout, its just awesome.

**1. The best solution.**

Use `display: flex;` for the box class, and add a container class for image as well.

```css
.box {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 500px;
    display: flex;

}

.box__image {
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 21px;
    float: left;
}

.box__text {}

.box__wrapper {}


.box__title {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.box__link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;

}
```

```html
<section class="task">
    <div class="task__holder">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="image-container">

                <img class="box__image"
                    src="https://dbcms.s3.amazonaws.com/devbridgecom/bcms/image/cdb81346f5ec4f708a53c58c48dbb288/knight-king-small.png"
                    alt="#">
            </div>
            <div class="box__wrapper">
                <h2 class="box__title">The Night King</h2>
                <p class="box__text">The Night King was created by the Children of the Forest during the Wars of the
                    First Men and the Children of the Forest and remained alive for about 10,000 years. It can be
                    assumed the magic that transformed him also gave him his longevity.</p>
                <p class="box__text">
                    The Night King was the master and the first of the <a href="#" class="box__link">white
                        walkers</a>, having existed since the age of the First Men. He was also the supreme leader
                    of the Army of the Dead.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**2. Solution without changing the template.**

Use `display: flex;` for the box class, and add `align-self: baseline;` for `box__image` class.

```css
.box {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 500px;
    display: flex;

}

.box__image {
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 21px;
    float: left;
    align-self: baseline;
}

.box__text {}

.box__wrapper {}


.box__title {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.box__link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;

}
```

```html
<section class="task">
    <div class="task__holder">
        <div class="box">

            <img class="box__image"
                src="https://dbcms.s3.amazonaws.com/devbridgecom/bcms/image/cdb81346f5ec4f708a53c58c48dbb288/knight-king-small.png"
                alt="#">
            <div class="box__wrapper">
                <h2 class="box__title">The Night King</h2>
                <p class="box__text">The Night King was created by the Children of the Forest during the Wars of the
                    First Men and the Children of the Forest and remained alive for about 10,000 years. It can be
                    assumed the magic that transformed him also gave him his longevity.</p>
                <p class="box__text">
                    The Night King was the master and the first of the <a href="#" class="box__link">white
                        walkers</a>, having existed since the age of the First Men. He was also the supreme leader
                    of the Army of the Dead.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Its clearly specified that the changes are to be made only to css. So why have you changed the HTML structure?

Comment: @CharleneVas have updated the answer, added solution without touching the template aswell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply add this to CSS, i think it would help you out :)

```
.box__image {
    border-radius: 20px;
   padding:21px;
   float: left;
  padding-bottom: 100%;

}

.box__text{
}
```

Comment: check the edited answer and do up vote and accepted if works

Comment: Really not an optimal solution. Sure, the `padding-bottom` prevents the text from wrapping underneath, but also disallows content to be aligned to the left for the entire page. Would definitely look at the other answers for inspiration and a more clean solution. @vytaute

Comment: @MarcHjorth i know but she don't want to change HTML, i think other approach  can be use of flexbox

Comment: @MarcHjorth she is just creating boxes so i don't think so she want to add certain things below this

Comment: @Avinashjain I'm aware, there are obviously a lot of ways to accomplish this without changing the markup. I'm just saying I don't agree with yours, especially not when there are a lot of other answers with better solutions. Don't take it personally, yours do work sure, it's just not a great solution for future projects ;)

Comment: @MarcHjorth ok, thats right someone has answered the solution of flexbox :)

Comment: Yes, other answers are little better. Still, thank you, it worked like a quick fix for me :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add `overflow: hidden` to the `.box__wrapper`class and add achange the margin top of the `.box__title` class to `margin: 20px 0 10px 0;`

```css
/* Make changes anywhere you need in CSS. Create CSS pseudo-elements if you need them. */

.box {
 border: 5px solid #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
 max-width: 500px;
 
}

.box__image {
 border-radius: 20px;
   padding:21px;
   float: left;
}

.box__text{
 
}
.box__wrapper {
   overflow: hidden
}


.box__title {
 font-weight: 700;
 margin: 20 0 10px 0;
}

.box__link {
 text-decoration: underline;
   color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-transform: capitalize;
   
}
```

```html
<section class="task">
  <div class="task__holder">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="box__image" src="https://dbcms.s3.amazonaws.com/devbridgecom/bcms/image/cdb81346f5ec4f708a53c58c48dbb288/knight-king-small.png" alt="#">
      <div class="box__wrapper">
        <h2 class="box__title">The Night King</h2>
        <p class="box__text">The Night King was created by the Children of the Forest during the Wars of the First Men and the Children of the Forest and remained alive for about 10,000 years. It can be assumed the magic that transformed him also gave him his longevity.</p>
        <p class="box__text">
          The Night King was the master and the first of the <a href="#" class="box__link">white walkers</a>, having existed since the age of the First Men. He was also the supreme leader of the Army of the Dead.
        </p>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display table and table-cell to fix this.

```
.box {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 500px;
    display: table;

}

.box__image {
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 21px;
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.box__text {}

.box__wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}


.box__title {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.box__link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;

}
```